# hover #a to style #one, where #one is a child element of #b, and #b is a sibling element of #a

Tags: html, css

Here's my html code

```
<body>

  <div id="b">    
    <div id="one"><div>
  </div>

  </div id="a">    
  </div>

</body>
```

Heres my css code (I've tried to place "~,+,>" between hover and the element I wish to style but none of those seem to work!

```
#a:hover  #one{
  background: white;
  -webkit-animation:spin 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation:spin 1s ease-in-out;
  animation:spin 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  opacity:1;    
  transition-delay:0s;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(180deg); } }
  @-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); } }
  @keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
  transform:rotate(180deg); } }
```

Comment: Your last div is invalid `</div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't allow you to select sibling elements and apply styles to them. If you want to retain the DOM structure the way you have it now, you would need to use Javascript to achieve what you want.

If you are flexible with changing the HTML structure a bit, consider encapsulating "a" and "b" divs inside a container , and apply hover styles for the container rather than "a" (but, this is as good as saying "b.hover")

Comment: Yes you can. [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Comment: good to know that this cant be done without Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: @Rob yes, but it cannot be used in OP's scenario, where his target element appears before the selector he'd be using. But then, I have no experience with "sibling combinators", please correct me if that is indeed possible.

Answer (score 0):

The + and ~ selectors get the siblings which are after the current node. There is no selector for 'previous sibling'. You need to apply style for such nodes with javascript.

```js
var divA = document.getElementById('a');

divA.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  document.getElementById('b').children[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
});
```

```css
#one {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="b">   
This is b
  <div id="one">This is one</div>
</div>

<div id="a">This is a  
</div>
```